# Using mjs in the project of Next.js

Tags: next.js, webpack-4

When I use mjs in my project of Next.js, I meet the error below:

```
Can't reexport the named export 'getLastPosition' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
ModuleDependencyError: Can't reexport the named export 'getLastPosition' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
    at Compilation.reportDependencyErrorsAndWarnings (D:\WorkHouse\scenario-bus\scenario-bus-fe-console\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1374:21)
    at D:\WorkHouse\scenario-bus\scenario-bus-fe-console\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1168:10
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\WorkHouse\scenario-bus\scenario-bus-fe-console\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (D:\WorkHouse\scenario-bus\scenario-bus-fe-console\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at Compilation.finish (D:\WorkHouse\scenario-bus\scenario-bus-fe-console\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1163:28)
    at D:\WorkHouse\scenario-bus\scenario-bus-fe-console\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:622:17
    at _done (eval at create (D:\WorkHouse\scenario-bus\scenario-bus-fe-console\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:9:1)
    at eval (eval at create (D:\WorkHouse\scenario-bus\scenario-bus-fe-console\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:31:22)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
ModuleDependencyError: Can't reexport the named export 'getLastPosition' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
    at Compilation.reportDependencyErrorsAndWarnings (D:\WorkHouse\scenario-bus\scenario-bus-fe-console\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1374:21)
    at D:\WorkHouse\scenario-bus\scenario-bus-fe-console\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1168:10
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\WorkHouse\scenario-bus\scenario-bus-fe-console\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (D:\WorkHouse\scenario-bus\scenario-bus-fe-console\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at Compilation.finish (D:\WorkHouse\scenario-bus\scenario-bus-fe-console\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1163:28)
    at D:\WorkHouse\scenario-bus\scenario-bus-fe-console\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:622:17
    at _done (eval at create (D:\WorkHouse\scenario-bus\scenario-bus-fe-console\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:9:1)
    at eval (eval at create (D:\WorkHouse\scenario-bus\scenario-bus-fe-console\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:31:22)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
ModuleDependencyError: Can't reexport the named export 'getLastPosition' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
    at Compilation.reportDependencyErrorsAndWarnings (D:\WorkHouse\scenario-bus\scenario-bus-fe-console\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1374:21)
    at D:\WorkHouse\scenario-bus\scenario-bus-fe-console\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1168:10
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\WorkHouse\scenario-bus\scenario-bus-fe-console\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (D:\WorkHouse\scenario-bus\scenario-bus-fe-console\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at Compilation.finish (D:\WorkHouse\scenario-bus\scenario-bus-fe-console\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1163:28)
    at D:\WorkHouse\scenario-bus\scenario-bus-fe-console\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:622:17
    at _done (eval at create (D:\WorkHouse\scenario-bus\scenario-bus-fe-console\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:9:1)
    at eval (eval at create (D:\WorkHouse\scenario-bus\scenario-bus-fe-console\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:31:22)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
```

It seems that the following code can't be used by Next.js.

```
export { getTrackSplit, getTrack, getLastPosition } from './webclient/position.mjs';
```

Nor does this code:

```
export * from './webclient/position.mjs';
```

So, how to use mjs in the project of Next.js?

Comment: What version of next.js are you using ?

Comment: "next": "^8.1.1-canary.46",

Answer (score 0):

It's my fault. I forgot to transpile the library. It works fine after transpiling the mjs library.